# How to effectively use a base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

I think using a base class would be very helpful for a set of classes I am defining for an application. In the (possibly incorrect) example below, I outline what I'm going for: a base class containing an attribute that I won't want to define multiple times. In this case, the base class will define the base part of a file path that each child class will then use to build out their own more specific paths.

However, it seems like I'd have to type in `parent_path` to the `__init__` method of the children classes anyway, regardless of the use of single inheritance from the base class.

```py
import pathlib

class BaseObject:
    def __init__(self, parent_path: pathlib.Path):
        self.parent_path = parent_path

class ChildObject(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, parent_path: pathlib.Path, child_path: pathlib.Path):
        super(ChildObject, self).__init__()
        self.full_path = parent_path.joinpath(child_path)

class ChildObject2(BaseObject):
    ...

class ChildObject3(BaseObject):
    ...
```

If this is the case, then is there any reason to use inheritance from a base class like this, other than to make it clearer what my implementation is trying to do?

Comment: You aren't passing the required arguments to you bass-class `__init__`, which requires a `parent_path` argument

Comment: telling the truth, i can't understand your question, we never used parentpath or childpath. what do you mean by 'EFFECTIVELY'?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an advantage for this implementation.  As you've noted, you still have to pass the `parent_path` into the child instantiation.  You also have to call the parent's `__init__`, which counteracts the one-line clarity "improvement".

For my eyes, you've already made it clear by using good attribute names.  I'd switch from `parent_path` to `base_path`, so the reader doesn't look for a parent object.

Alternately, you might want to make that a *class* attribute of the parent: set it once, and let all the objects share it by direct reference, rather than passing in the same value for every instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct that you have to provide `parent_path` into the `__init__` call of the parent, that is `super(ChildObject, self).__init__(parent_path)` (you missed to provide parent_path in your example).

However, this is Python, so there is usually help so you can avoid writing boilerplate code. In this case, I would recommend to use the [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) library. With this you can even avoid writing your **init** classes all together.

Answer (score 0):

To get a usefulness of such inheritance scheme - make your `BaseObject` more flexible and accept optional (keyword) arguments:

```
import pathlib

class BaseObject:
    def __init__(self, parent_path: pathlib.Path, child_path: pathlib.Path=None):
        self.parent_path = parent_path
        self.full_path = parent_path.joinpath(child_path) if child_path else parent_path

class ChildObject(BaseObject):
    ...

class ChildObject2(BaseObject):
    ...

class ChildObject3(BaseObject):
    ...


co = ChildObject(pathlib.Path('.'), pathlib.Path('../text_files'))
print(co, vars(co))
# <__main__.ChildObject object at 0x7f1a664b49b0> {'parent_path': PosixPath('.'), 'full_path': PosixPath('../text_files')}
```